# Show ListView based on selected spinner

Tags: android, fragment, android-spinner

In my first fragment I have 2 spinners and 1 button

```
spinner1(Type of Foods)
spinner2(Color)
```

What I want is if user choose a type of food in first spinner and what color and click the button they should be directed to `FragmentTwo` with listview depends on the selected value

For Example: User choose Vegetable in `spinner1` and choose a color of Green `spinner2` after they click the button they will go to `FragmentTwo` with a ListView of Vegetables that has a color of Green

**FragmentOne()**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

Spinner spinner1, spinner2;

public FragmentOne() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_two, container,
            false);

    // Spinner
    // Spinner
    spinner1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spFood);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.food_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

    spinner2 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spColor);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.color_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    // Button
    Button btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //what to do

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentTwo());
             ft.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

`tvType` value of `spinner1` ,
`tvColor` value of `spinner2`

**FragmentTwo()**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

TextView tv1, tv2;
ListView listView;

public FragmentTwo() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodlist, container,
                  false);

      //TextView
      tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
      tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvColor);

      //ListView
      listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      return view;
}
}
```

**FragmentTwo XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Type of Food"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvColor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Color"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: what you have tried? did you try `spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();`?

Comment: yes and I can't make it working

Comment: what is your mean about "I can't make it working"? any error? wrong result?

Comment: no error but app keep crashing

Comment: if app crashed so you have an error in your code, so post logcat error and post what you have tried

Comment: @KenHollis where did you set adapter to spinner. Post that code too.

Comment: where app is crashing after button clicked or before it.

Comment: @KenHollis Try my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

In your `FragmentOne.class`

```
Button btnSearch = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String type = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();  
        String color = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("type", type);
        bundle.putString("color", color);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

and `FragmentTwo.class`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.foodlist, container,
                  false);

      //TextView
      tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvType);
      tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvColor);

      String type = "",color = "";
      Bundle args = getArguments();
      if (args  != null && args.containsKey("type"))
          type = args.getString("type");

      if (args  != null && args.containsKey("color"))
          color = args.getString("color");

      tv1.setText(type); 
      tv2.setText(color);

      //ListView
      listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      return view;
}
```

Comment: it's working, but still have my problem, in my example If user choose Vegetable in `spinner1` and pick a color of Green in `spinner2` that will show a ListView of vegetables with color of green

Comment: @KenHollis compare **type** and **color** in `FragmentTwo.class` and populate that in `ListView`.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @KenHollis where you are going to populate `ListView`. post that code.

Comment: I still don't know what exactly to do sorry first time making this can you just give me an example of what I need to do ? really sorry

Comment: do I need to make fragments,xml for every options in the spinner ?

Comment: @KenHollis k don't be sorry. Where did you set adapter for `ListView`? that means you are already populated spinner like that for ListView.